# jQuery/Javascript: make outer div height unchangeable and inner div height fluid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm using Adsense responsive banner and I'm having one problem. 
I have 2 divs, one inner and the another one outer, the outer div has a fixed value, like 160px, the inner div has the same alue, but the inner div is being expanded by its content, which is the responsive adsense ad. Here's an example of the html structure:

```
<div style="display:block; height:160px; width:100%">
  <div>ADSENSE RESPONSIVE (Comes as inline-block)</div>
</div>
```

What I need is way, using jQuery or any other javascript library, to make the outer div's height non-expandable (Maybe according to the CSS responsive layout), but the inner div should be the one adjusting its height according to the outer div's height.

Here's what's happening:

[image]

FULL CODE

jQuery + HTML:

```
    <div id="adsenselisting">
    <div id="adsenselistingadvert">



    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- Responsive Adsense In Listing -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
    style="display:block"
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    data-ad-slot="64XXXXXXXX"
    data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({})});
    </script>



    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
  /* FLUID HEIGHT LAYOUT FOR ADSENSE */
/* FLUID HEIGHT LAYOUT FOR ADSENSE */
#adsenselistingadvert { margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; max-height:100%;  border:2px solid blue;   }

#adsenselisting {  display: inline-block; width:100%; max-width:100%;  padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 12px;   border:2px solid red;
}     

@media only screen and (min-width : 1px) {
#adsenselisting, #adsenselistingadvert { height:100px }
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
#adsenselisting, #adsenselistingadvert { height:130px }
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
#adsenselisting, #adsenselistingadvert {  height:130px }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 640px) {
#adsenselisting, #adsenselistingadvert {  height:160px }
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 720px) {
#adsenselisting, #adsenselistingadvert {  height:200px}
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 960px) {
#adsenselisting, #adsenselistingadvert {  height:200px }
}
```

Everything works just fine, I just want the height not be expandable.

Comment: Use `overflow-y: scroll`

Comment: It's against google TOS.

Comment: the inner div does not seem to be expanding, what seem to be happening rather is the content is spilling out of the inner div so as @ameenulla0007 suggested you'll need to set the overflow or resize the image to fit to the max height of the inner-div which is already inheriting the outer div's height.

Comment: But it's a Google's responsive ad unit, is that even possible and allowed?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with google's add rules. If you are only allowing a static 160px of height on your page for adds then setting max-height:100% should keep the add content within the inner div.
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
    style="display:block; max-height:100%"
    data-ad-client  . . .

Comment: According to this you are allowed to set the ad size with css, See FAQ at bottom: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3221666